# Javascript vs C# Reference Type

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new the C# and found that the reference type definition different than JavaScript.

Can anyone explain why C# returns 30, unlike JS that returns 20?

**Javascript**

```
class Person {
  constructor(age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}

let person = new Person(20);

const old = (age) => {
  age += 10;
};

old(person.age);
console.log(person.age); // 20
```

**C#**

```
    class Program
    {
        public class Person
        {
            public int Age;
        }
        public static void Old(Person person)
        {
            person.Age += 10;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person() {Age = 20};
            Old(person);
            Console.WriteLine(person.Age); // 30
        }
      
    }
```

Comment: The first example doesn't change the object property value. It modifies the local variable and then doesn't return it. Pass `person` instead, then modify the property of that object.

Comment: You're not doing the same - one time you do `old (age) => { age += 10; };` the other `Old(Person person) { person.Age += 10; }`. If you change your JS to `old = (person) =>  { person.age += 10; }` **or** your C# to `Old(int age) { age += 10; }` you'd get the same results.

Comment: Please don't change the question in a way that makes existing answers invalid. You do not need to put the corrected code into it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your JS example, you're simply passing the age - a simple number. In your C# example, you're passing the `Person` object itself.

If you change your JS to

```
const old = (person) => {
  person.age += 10;
};
```

You'll get the outcome you're looking for

Comment: Hi, I updated the JS's Old Method to the following but result still 20?
const old = (person) => {
  person.age = 30;
};

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/tatikigupe/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds Remember you need to call `old(person)` now, not `old(person.age)`

Comment: @Jim_Mcdonalds, make sure you're only passing the `person` to your `old` function when you call it